# Cross database DML query in azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Is it possible to use DML commands like insert, update from cross database in azure SQL.

In my requirement I'm running one SP on DB1 after execution i want to update status in a table that belongs to DB2. I'm using azure SQL. Is there any way to call SPs from cross database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can leverage the [elastic database query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview) feature which supports Cross-Database Queries. Check [sp_execute_remote](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt703714) for details of executing t-sql queries on remote Azure SQL Databases.

Here is a similar thread for your reference: [Call stored procedure from Elastic Database in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131580/call-stored-procedure-from-elastic-database-in-azure)